# Keeping code in multiple SVN repositories with git locally

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am working on a project where there are two SVN repositories. One is for external use, and our interfacing with partners on the project, and the other if for purely internal use.

I have a folder (src) which exists on the external repository. My desire is to keep that code in a second src folder on the internal repository so as to be able to commit internally, and when the code is stable, commit to the external repository.

In addition to this I want to manage code locally on my machine with git.

To this end, I have looked at git-svn.

Could anyone explain the best way to manage this? I am leaning toward having a branch for each svn repo, ( localsvn and externalsvn ) and working with local as the default, merging into external when I want to commit to it, and keeping git running in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current way I have dealt with this, is having two seperate version of the code. The branching system did not work out for me.

I have a version for the remote repo, managed with git-svn, and a version for the local repo, also managed with git-svn. When I want to move from local to remote, or vice versa, I just move the code over with a script, and merge, and finally upload.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, but you'll need to play around with one of the more esoteric features of `git svn`: the `-R` (remote name option).

Create a `git svn` repository using `git svn init` for the local code as normal, then take a look at the `.git/config` file. There'll be a section called `[svn-remote "svn"]`. Copy this entire section, renaming it to something like `[svn-remote "external"]`, edit the `url` field to point to the external repository, and update the other fields to give them unique names.

I'd expect the relevant parts of the config file to look something like this after you're done:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://local.svn/repository/root
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
[svn-remote "external"]
    url = http://external.svn/repository/root
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/ext-trunk
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/ext-*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/ext-*
```

If you now do `git svn` operations, it'll fetch from the local repository. If you add `-Rexternal`, you'll instead work on the external repository. To do your initial fetch, you'll therefore need to run both the below:

```
git svn fetch
git svn fetch -Rexternal
```